# Add an anchor to the `Ignored Tags preferences` link

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

I propose to add [`#ignored-wrapper`](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/#ignored-wrapper) to the end of the link in the comment `Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags`.

Currently the link leads to the top of the page "Preferences". Then you need to look for the desired section.

It will be convenient to move exactly to the place where you want to go:

> Hiding questions because of your [Ignored Tags preferences](//stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/#ignored-wrapper) for tags